# Can't read a String from URL using NSData

Tags: json, swift, url

I'm using `NSData(contentsOfURL)` constructor to load the data from URL (server returns a JSON in .txt file). Date loads just fine, but I can't create `NSString(date:)` out of it. I can save this data using `NSFileManager.createFileAtPath()` and it's correct, but `NSString` created out of this data will be nil, also I can't create a JSON using swiftyJSON.

If I execute the same query in browser it will download a filename.txt.js.

Web-sniffer shows this header: "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="f.txt"".

Comment: why not you using Haneke?

Comment: @Dato'MohammadNurdin I'm developing for OS X

Comment: I mean Haneke framework for image cache.

Comment: Why use a thirdparty framework when our OS is way better in handling such.

Comment: @HelgeBecker in Swift you should unwrap every JSON field you want access

Answer (score 0):

try

```
let str = NSString(data: data, encoding: UInt)
```

Comment: My NSData is not optional